# how to block an action if user does not have enough coins?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm fixing a word game and I've made a button that allows a user to get a tip... but the tip cost 10 coins.

how can i block the action if the user doesn't have any coins left and at the same time Alert the user to buy coins?

```
-(IBAction)btnHint:(id)sender {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

    CGPoint center = [hints center];
    center.x = 160;
    center.y = 230;
    [hints setCenter:center];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
    hintView.text = @"founded in 1996, and is a sub of telecome";

    coins = coins -10;
}
```

Comment: Add an `if` statement that checks the condition.

Comment: then show UIAlert with your message

Comment: @rmaddy yes but if I do an if stamens the animation will still rise and the tip will be exposed, the animation also needs to be blocked to not rise, how is this done? if (coins == 0) {
        [hintView setHidden:YES];
    }
words to hide the hint, but it does nothing to stop the animation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
- (IBAction)btnHint:(id)sender {
    if (/* some condition that determines if there are enough coins */) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

        CGPoint center = [hints center];
        center.x = 160;
        center.y = 230;
        [hints setCenter:center];

        [UIView commitAnimations];
        hintView.text = @"founded in 1996, and is a sub of telecome";

        coins = coins -10;
    } else {
        // show alert
    }
}
```

BTW - you really should migrate to the modern block-based `UIView` animation instead of the old way you are using.

Comment: Yeah well I have a bigger problem with these if statements, the coins are not adding up properly, whats the proper way to add up coins and scores?

Comment: That's a separate question. If this one is answered then accept this answer and post another question as needed.